# Rails Gem Client Side Validations html struct

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, client-side

My project use Twitter Bootstrap CSS Framework,so my html like this.

```
<div class="control-group ">
  <label class="control-label" for="user_name">Username</label> 
  <div class="controls">
    <input data-validate="true" id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

When validate failed, Client Side Validation change it to:

```
<div class="control-group ">
  <div class="field_with_errors">
    <label class="control-label" for="user_name">Username</label>
  </div> 
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="field_with_errors">
      <input data-validate="true" id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text">
      <label for="user_name" class="message">Please input Username</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want to user Bootstrap Form validation Css:
The html is:

```
<div class="control-group error">
   <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputError">
         <span class="help-inline">Please correct the error</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to do?

Answer (score 0):

try this gem: [realtime validations](http://rubygems.org/gems/realtime-validations)